# Use sass parent (ampersand) selector with fixed root class

Tags: css, sass

In the following code example I generate two squares that ideally should turn red.

The first div `.with-root` currently stays blue, the second div `.without-root` turns red. I expect this behaviour, but don't see a proper solution to turn the `.with-root` div red as well.

Note the difference in the scss file: the first div works with a fixed parent selector, the second one doesn't have a parent. For CSS specificity I need to work with the .with-root {} wrapper.

```
.with-root {
  .with-root__element {
    display: block;
    width: 5rem;
    height: 5rem;
    background: blue;
    &--red & {
      &__item {
        background: red;
      }   
    }
  }
}

.without-root {
  &__element {
    display: block;
    width: 5rem;
    height: 5rem;
    background: blue;
    &--red & {
      &__item {
        display: block;
        width: 5rem;
        height: 5rem;
        background: red;
      }   
    }
  }
}
```

The codepen can be found here: https://codepen.io/studiotwist/pen/OzMOmr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well now that I hopefully understood your question I deleted my wrong idea before and the following solution should work.

Maybe there could be a logic erorr. You have actually three class definitions of `.with-root__element` and two of them are extended with `--red` and `__item`, but the 3rd one is however an extra class which comes in conflict with the other two. You're basically concatenating the endings `--red` and `__item` with the parent selector `*__element`. Also, the `--red` class is nested inside the `*__element` one without ending in your CSS but in HTML it is not. `*__element` and `*__element--red` are attached in the same HTML tag.

**DEBUG**

Only showing the first DIV.

```
.with-root {
  .with-root__element {
    display: block;
    width: 5rem;
    height: 5rem;
    background: blue;
    &--red {
      //@error &; // this reference contains the entire document root including the root element .with-root which is wrong
      #{&} &__item { 
        //@error #{&} &__item; // this is a wrong concatenation plus it takes the entire root with it
        background: red; // thus, this won't render
      }   
    }
  }
}
```

[Debug in action @ Sassmeister](https://www.sassmeister.com/gist/6755ba2df06942a4138591fd11ee7998)

---

**POSSIBLE FIX**

```
@mixin bg($bg) {
  width: 5rem;
  height: 5rem;
  background: $bg;
}

.with-root__element {
  @include bg(blue);
  $this: &;
  @at-root {
    .with-root {
      #{$this}--red #{$this}__item {
        @include bg(red);
      }
    }
  }
}

.without-root {
  &__element {
    @include bg(blue);
    &--red &__item {
      @include bg(red);
    }   
  }
}
```

[Fork](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MrebPP)

`@at-root` is a directive which is useful for your issue as it basically crops the nesting level of the selector and styles can be defined inside the root-body by referencing the parent selector instead of the entire root. So I added a variable `$this` which will cache the reference. `display: block` is not needed as div elements have it by default. Sorry about the mixin, it's a habit. `--red` and `__item` have now the refence selector `*__element`.

[@at-root Documentation](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#_at-root__at-root)

Comment: My example is not clear enough apparently. The css is purely for demo purposes to demo the fact that if i work with a fixed parent selector `.with-root .with-root__element { ... }` I can't use the `&--red & { ... }` selector. I am looking to find a way to be able to use it in a decent way.

Comment: I re-issued my answer and hopefully I understand know and thus the fix here. If not then let me know, I will delete. Also it would not harm to read and be aware of the [XY-Trap](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).